# How can I have unlimited keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keybindings

There's only so many keys in a keyboard, I want limitless
possibilities with key bindings by being able to bind key sequences
to actions.

How can I bind an action to an extended shortcut?

Let's say

```
Control-x-k to    'open textedit'
```

I know there's no hardware limitation preventing long keyboard shortcuts, because with emacs you can do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'open-something)
```

[ref](http://emacslife.com/read-lisp-tweak-emacs/beginner-3-make-things-more-convenient.html)

Comment: Recently I scoured my shortcut list for rare gaps - I needed a shortcut to automatically type `and` and I found one: **ctr-alt-a-n-d**. Really easy to remember...

Comment: did you mean "open sourced" when you said "sourced" ?

Comment: to scoure ≠ to source

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that macOS will let you add key sequences in System Preference -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. However, you should be able to do it, but you will most likely have to manually add shortcuts in plist files.

I think the answer provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1340224/how-to-enable-emacs-keybindings-on-macos-globally), as well as [this](https://github.com/ttscoff/KeyBindings) repository, will help you create custom keyboard shortcuts.

You can also check out Keyboard Maestro's [FAQ](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_use_a_multiple_keystroke_trigger) on their workarounds to key sequence shortcuts.